# How to set community font size

Tags: community, css, experience-cloud

I inherited half baked community with some custom templates, few components, builder items and a custom layout (aura, implements `forceCommunity:themeLayout`).

Was wondering what is the correct, best or preferred way to change font size centrally? Components seem to set their own font, some use slds text sizing classes, some use font-size set in CSS. I don't really wanna go thru everything to change one by one, but open to do if there is not another way.

So far I found [Overriding Standard Tokens (Developer Preview)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.212.0.lightning.meta/lightning/tokens_standard_overrides.htm) for components and Override CSS section in Experience Builder (which my guess injects style in head markup).

Comment: This is a limitation refer the https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdjLwUAJ/lightning-communities-font-size